# Image renaming script deletes images from server

Tags: php

guys, ran into problem:
when asked, script randomly chooses image from the folder and renames it (by pattern: name+age... etc.). It works fine: fast and correctly in short sequences.
After approximately 30k requests (in total in month) I found out that only 1k images out of 6k remained. I periodically re-upload images, but just curious what is the source of losses.

```
function gen_post($sex){
$way = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$img_array = scandir("img/$sex");
$fin = mt_rand(5, 8);
$maxi = count($img_array)-1;
$beg = 0;
while ($beg<$fin) {
$im = $img_array[mt_rand(2,$maxi)];
$img_name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', "$rand_name"); //name from file
$new_im = $img_name . '-' . $age . '-' . $weight . '.jpg';  //generates name from variables
rename("$way/img/$sex/$im", "$way/img/$sex/$new_im");
$img = "$sex/$new_im";
//------------------- <HTML block> ------------------------
include('template/bloc_html.php');
//------------------- </HTML block> ------------------------
$beg++;
}
}
```

Comment: do you check if the new name already exists and prevent it? if not, it could be due to coincidence, if the new name already exists it will overwrite the old file leaving you with one less file each time this happens.

Comment: The probability is low, but I will test the case with random id name fragment.

Comment: Yep, the problem was with the names taken. Thanks a lot.